# Variance of $\chi^2$ statistic depends on $df$ but not on $n$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have an $r\times c$ contingency table. The chi-square statistic for the table is equal to $\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{rc} (O_i - E_i)^2 / E_i$, where $O_{i}$ are the observed and expected counts for cell $i$ respectively. Let $n$ be the total number of counts. Then the variance of $\chi^2$ is given by $2 \times (r-1) \times (c-1)$, where $(r-1) \times (c-1)$ is the number of degrees of freedom.  My question is the following – why does the variance not depend only on the $df$ and not on the total number of counts, $n$?  It would seem to me that if $n$ is smaller there would be greater variability in the observed counts.  If $n$ is extremely large, the observed counts would be very precise, leading to a more precise $\chi^2$ statistic.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the information that went into computing the expected values $E_i.$  These issues are extensively discussed in other threads.  Use keywords like "degrees of freedom" to search our site.

Comment: Sure the expected values $E_{i} = np_{i}$ and so depend on $n$. But the issue remains that if $n$ is larger both $O_{i}$ and $E_{i}$ are more precise and so $Var(\chi^2)$ should still intuitively depend on $n$.

Comment: Then it's important to modify your intuition: searching our site can help with that.  Your premise is questionable, though: the statistic already accounts for the precision in the $O_i$ in dividing by $E_i,$ which is a (close) proxy for their variance.

Comment: "$rc$" is a misleading choice for the d.f in a chi-squared on a contingency table, as $r$ and $c$ conventionally stand for the number of rows and columns of the contingency table respectively, but then it is not the case that the df are $r \times c$ (almost never; it's actually somewhat tricky to come up with a realistic situation where you have that; if you are in such a situation, it might be worth mentioning it). Most typically the d.f. parameter in a test of independence is $(r-1)\times (c-1)$. .

Comment: @Glen_b yes you are right. The $df$ for a $\chi^2$ is typically $(r-1)  \times (c-1)$. I've corrected my original post.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I see what you mean. It is the division by $E_i$ which normalizes the distribution. I suppose a simple analogy would be the z-statistic (for a Normal variate) which has fixed variance of 1 regardless of sample size, due to the standard error (of the Normal variate) in its denominator.

Comment: You missed a consequence of that correction which entails a second correction -- if the df is $(r-1) \times (c-1)$ the variance is not $2rc$.

Comment: @Glen_b ok the variance is corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a different question, and then argue by analogy:

Suppose $X$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, so with mean $np$, and variance $np(1-p)$ and fourth moment about the mean of $3n^2p^2(1-p)^2-6np^2(1-p)^2-np(1-p)$.

Then consider $Y = \frac{(X-\mathbb E[X])^2}{\mathbb E[X]}$.  You can show that $Y$ has mean $\frac{np(1-p)}{np}=1-p$ which does not depend on $n$ and $Y$ has variance $2(1-p)^2 -\frac{6}{n}(1-p)^2+\frac{1}{n}\frac{1-p}{p}$; as $n$ increases, the variance of $Y$ tends towards $2(1-p)^2$, which also does not depend on $n$.

Now coming back to your question, one ${(O_i-E_i)^2/E_i}$ is rather similar to the binomial case albeit affected by the row and column constraints, and similarly $\sum_{i=1}^{rc} (O_{i} – E_{i})^{2} / E_{i}$  is similar to the sum of an constant number of these though with some small covariances.  So it is reasonable that, as $n$ increases, the variance of your $\chi^2$ heads towards a finite positive value which does not depend substantially on $n$.

In simpler form, ${(X-\mathbb E[X])^2}$ has a mean which is $O(n)$ and a variance which is $O(n^2)$ so $Y$ has a mean and a variance which are both $O(1)$.  Similarly $(O_i-E_i)^2$ has a mean which is $O(n)$ and a variance which is $O(n^2)$ so ${(O_i-E_i)^2/E_i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{rc} (O_{i} – E_{i})^{2} / E_{i}$ have means and variances which are $O(1)$.

It is the division by $\mathbb E[X]$ and by $E_i$ which largely removes the effect of $n$ both on both the means and the variances, at least when $n$ is large.